# Cache emulation in jmeter

Tags: caching, jmeter, load-testing

I'm running some load tests with jmeter on a page which has about 70 requests per user including the embedded resources like css,html etc., and was using cache manager to get cached browser behaviour in jmeter.

The thing is that to do so I need to run the test two times consecutively, which is a problem as I need to test it for a high number of users and I only need the cache scenario separately.

Is there any way to precache the cacheble resources in jmeter and run the test so that I will be able to just load test the cache scenario?

Comment: unsure if this is the best way to do this, but you could have 1 thread in a thread-group run first to prime the cache, before sequentially starting your actual test thread-group?

Comment: I tried to to run the test as you mentioned by creating two thread groups one to prime the cache and other one for the main test and added a single cache manager to be shared by the two thread groups,but with this i am unable achieve the required result@RaGe.Is there a way to share cache between thread groups?

Comment: On closer reading of cache-manager documentation, apparently the cache is per thread, It is not even shared among threads in a thread group. I do not know if a way to share cache between threads or thread-groups.